# Alternate name for localhost not working

Tags: server, apache2, localhost

I tried using an alternate name for localhost.

```
127.0.0.1   localhost test.dev
```

This doesn't show apache2 page when I use test.dev but works when I type localhost.

Also I tired using

```
127.0.0.1   localhost test
```

This worked with http but not with https, can anyone help?

Comment: Any Help :-( ??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After searching for sometime I found that it's google's fault :P
Google made the .dev domain a TLD, or Top Level Domain, so now, without an SSL certificate (HTTPS connection) you can't access your local environment. You should be able to solve it by changing the extension, using something like .app, or .devel

Answer (score 1):

If you are working locally, you most certainly *can* point any domain to your localhost within `/etc/hosts`. I do this all the time for development. What you will want to do, however, is put each domain on its own line.

For example, your `/etc/hosts` file might look something like this:

```
127.0.0.1       localhost
127.0.0.1       test.dev
127.0.0.1       another.dev
127.0.0.1       yet.another.dev
```

The `.dev` addresses above would all be handled by the local web server.

Where this can fall down, though, is when you're using a browser that wants to use its own DNS mechanisms. When this happens, it doesn't matter what you have in `/etc/hosts`, because the browser will ask an external DNS provider directly and cache the result.

If you would like to avoid TLDs that exist, note that `.app` is a valid TLD [as per Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/.app_(gTLD)), and `.devel` is certainly free to use. I generally stick to `.local` for things on my local machine, `.vbox` for VirtualBox resources, and `.{environment}` when testing against specific environments (Docker, EC2, etc.). That said, there is nothing stopping you from using a `.com` in `/etc/hosts` if you choose ... aside from your browser.

Comment: .dev on the next line didn't work for me but its fine, we have a way around.